# После добавления Sitemap перестали работать ссылки

Tags: python, django, sitemap

Добавил на сайт динамический sitemap. Все работает, sitemap.xml создается и все генерируемые страницы там отображаются. Но после этого при заходе на любую станицу сайта ошибки.

**sitemaps.py**

```
class AudiobookSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "always"
    priority = 0.8
    protocol = 'http'

    def items(self):
        return AudioBook.objects.all()

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.created

    def location(self, obj):
        return '/audiobook/%s' % (obj.slug)


class BookGenreSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "always"
    priority = 0.9
    protocol = 'http'

    def items(self):
        return BookGenre.objects.all()

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.created

    def location(self, obj):
        return '/audiobook_genre/%s' % (obj.slug)
```

**urls.py**

```py
app_name = "main"

sitemaps = {
    'audiobook':AudiobookSitemap,
    'audiobook_genre':BookGenreSitemap,
}

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    path('sitemap.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, 
    name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),

    url('search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search'),

    path("author/<slug:post_slug>/", author, name='author'),
    path("cycle/<slug:post_slug>/", cycle, name='cycle'),

    path("audiobook/<slug:post_slug>/", audiobook, name='audiobook'),
    path("audiobook_genre/<slug:post_slug>/", audiobook_genre, 
    name='audiobook_genre')

]
```

**Ну и сама ошибка при заходе на сайт -**

```
Reverse for 'search' not found. 'search' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```